# Discord.py bot not reading other bot's messages

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

When I run the python code below, it doesn't pick up messages from other bots:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message)
```

Is there any way to make so that my discord.py bot does pick up messages from other bots?

Comment: Does it trigger for any messages?

Comment: It triggers for all messages that aren't from bots

Comment: Do you have any other `on_message` events?

Comment: No I don't have any other on_message events

Comment: Can you create a minimal and complete example that can reproduce your problem? Your current code should work for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to just use the `channel.history(limit=10).flatten()` and `channel.fetch_message(ID)` functions and put them in a loop, which also works well for my application.

Answer (score 2):

Discord.py bots are set to ignore messages sent by other bots, [see the code here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/862d509d2e39f9d550ec3dff1e7d08fc6b3b5b8d/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L950-L979) - more specifically lines 972 and 973:

```py
if message.author.bot:
    return
```

To work around this, you can subclass the bot, and override the process_commands method as shown below:

```py
class UnfilteredBot(commands.Bot):
    """An overridden version of the Bot class that will listen to other bots."""

    async def process_commands(self, message):
        """Override process_commands to listen to bots."""
        ctx = await self.get_context(message)
        await self.invoke(ctx)
```

and run your code using this bot instead. Probably not the best to use in production, but is a good way to facilitate testing of your bot via another bot

Answer (score 1):

As the messages are from bots, could it be because the bots are using embeds? Because discord cannot print message from embeds(Maybe unless if you use `message.embeds`) Check if the messages the bots are sending are plain text instead of embeds